# C# + chrome-driver : How to fix - cannot find Chrome binary/Chrome failed to start: crashed/Failed to create a Chrome process?

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, chromedriver, chrome, selenium-webdriver-c#

I am trying to run selenium using **chrome-driver** in my project. While creating object of chrome-driver facing errors :

> **Message "unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary\n
> (Driver info: chromedriver=81.0.4044.20**

Please let me know if anyone face/fix this issue.

**Error 1 :**

> **{"unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.\n (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)**

**Error 2 :**

> **{"unknown error: Failed to create a Chrome process.\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome is currently on v91 and it needs a driver to match. Install Chrome in its default location and make sure it is updated. Then get the latest Chromedriver. There's a NuGet package for chromedriver if you prefer to manage it that way.

Comment: Thanks for quick response @kirbycope. yes I have installed chrome v 90.0. matched chrome-driver and req. NuGet packages has been installed. No error observed. Still getting error - Failed to crated a Chrome process\n . . .

Comment: @NarendraC note he said Chrome is on v91, not v90, which you've mentioned...

Comment: Yeah, the joy of auto updates.

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks . Yes I have tried with v91 and v90. Today I am planning to downgrade even further, That is the only option I can see as of now.

Comment: Matched chrome & driver version. Installed chrome in its default location @kirbycope as suggested.Still observed errors. Small fine tuning resolve issue.  
Catch was - I uninstalled my Chrome browser manually and install it again. Voila :) Everything started working as expected.